Extract highly similar cells between two seurat objects
I have run long-read sequencing on full cDNA from mouse using 10X Genomics scGEX 3’. Next, I filtered reads matching my SNP of interest, followed by extracting cell barcodes from those reads. Then I created a Seurat object1 with 309 cells and the unfiltered reads make up a Seurat object2 that has 3646 cells; these 309 cells are the only cells that express the gene containing the SNP of interest. The Seurat objects are from the same experiment.
How would I extract highly similar (high correlation / similar gene expression) cells from object2 and add to object1?
I want to merge them back to the object with 309 cells. Object1 should constitute ~71% of the cells in object2.

Okay, you want to merge them back, and then what - what is the overarching problem that you're trying to solve? Where did the 71% number come from - why is the "nearest" 126 cells important? How should cell / expression similarity be calculated?
